# Genereted header file form ui file not visible?

Tags: c++, qt

I use QtCreator and QtDesigner to make a simple dialog. But when I tun Qmake I don't get a generated header file from the .ui file. I can use the member variables such as buttons and labels which I have made with QtDesigner. Is it normal this header to be invisible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

yes the file will be hidden

you can find the generated header in the build directory (a folder next to the project folder with) named ui_*.h this will also be where the moc_*.cpp files will be put

Comment: Thanks alot. You were right. I found it in my build directory :)